# How can I retrieve the remaining items in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a simple for loop iterating over a list of items. At some point, I know it will break. How can I then return the remaining items?

```
for i in [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]:
    try: 
        some_func(i)
    except:
        return(remaining_items) # if some_func fails i.e. for c I want to return [c,d,e,f,g]
```

I know I could just take my inital list and delete the the items from the beginning for every iteration one by one. But is there maybe some native Python function for this or something more elegant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of `enumerate` that yields both the element and its index in the list.

```py
myList = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
for index, item in enumerate(myList):
    try: 
        some_func(item)
    except:
        return myList[index:]
```

[Test-it online](https://onlinegdb.com/OYkdcQwac)

Comment: Much nicer than my `dropwhile` :D

Comment: @azro Thanks ;). Although. it works, and thank for showing me it because i didn't know it exist. I should dig in itertools more...

Comment: There is many default itertools nice method, but https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes also shows new ones from default ones

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.dropwhile`, you use a `test` method to apply `some_func`, when it raises an error, the test becomes False and so it stops and `dropwhile` return the remaining ones

```
from itertools import dropwhile
    
def my_fct():
    def test(v):
        try:
            some_func(v)
            return False
        except:
            return True    
    return list(dropwhile(test, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def test():
    myList = [1,2,3,4,0,7,8,9]
    for index, item in enumerate(myList):
        try: 
            print(index,item)
            1/item
        except:
            return(myList[index:])
```