# How to get remaining items when iterating over dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a simple for loop iterating over a dictionary. At some point, I know it will break. How can I then return a dictionary of the remaining items?

For a list, this can be done [by indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65577801/how-can-i-retrieve-the-remaining-items-in-a-for-loop-in-python). Is there a similar way for dictionaries?

```
example_dict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e'}

def dict_loop(mydict):
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(mydict.items()):
        try:
            assert (k !=3) # mimicking an error
            print(i, k, v)
        except: 
            return remaining_dictionary # if fails for key 3, should return {3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e'}
       
dict_loop(example_dict)
```

Comment: You can remember what you have seen in a list or set and then go through what you have not seen yet.

Comment: I think the answer will depend on which version of Python 3.x+ you have. In some versions the insertion order of key-value pairs in a dictionary is not guaranteed, in others it's an implementation detail, in others it's guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the current index value of the enumerator to slice the remaining keys and construct a return dict via a dictionary comprehension.

```
example_dict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e'}

def dict_loop(mydict):
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(mydict.items()):
        try:
            assert (k !=3) # mimicking an error
            print(i, k, v)
        except:
            remaining_keys = list(mydict.keys())[i:]
            return {k: mydict[k] for k in remaining_keys}

remaining_dict = dict_loop(example_dict)
print(f'remaining_dict = {remaining_dict}')
```

Output

```
0 1 a
1 2 b
remaining_dict = {3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could create an iterator over `mydict.items()`:

```
example_dict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}

def dict_loop(mydict):
    it = iter(mydict.items())
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(it):
        try:
            assert (k != 3)  # mimicking an error
            print(i, k, v)
        except:
            ret = {k: v}    # need to add the failed key-value pair
            ret.update(it)  # and update with the remaining elements

ret = dict_loop(example_dict)
print(ret)  # {3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

this will iterate once only over your original dictionary.

`enumerate` is not needed in order to find the remaining items.

Answer (score 0):

```
example_dict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e'}
keys = list(example_dict.keys())
while len(keys) > 0:
    key = keys.pop(0)
    try:
            assert (key !=3) # mimicking an error
            print(example_dict[key])
    except: 
            return {key:example_dict[key] for key in keys}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, `enumerate` returns an object similar to a generator, which you can use to obtain the remaining items. You need to make a slight adaptation to your looping only:

```
>>> a = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
>>> en = enumerate(a.items())
>>> for i, (k, v) in en:
...     try:
...             assert i == 1
...     except:
...             print(list(en))
... 
[(1, ('B', 2)), (2, ('C', 3))]
```

The complexity is entirely handled by Python.